# Is it recommended to disable ssl verification instead of providing ca certificate in production?

Tags: ssl, curl

Our client has provided self signed certificate for one of the internal service. We are acceessing this service in our shell script using curl. In order to connect to that service we need to provide certiface in our curl command or we can disable ssl verification using -k in our curl command. We wanted to know is it safe to disable ssl verification on production?

Comment: Certainly not. It is radically insecure, as it trusts all certificates issued by anyone, including all attackers. It isn't even recommended in testing, as testing is supposed to exercise the same code as production, and as there is a considerable risk that the insecure testing code will get into production without being made secure. If you don't want it secure why use SSL at all?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**NO**

Disabling certificate verification removes all security properties from the HTTPS connection. It is strongly advised that you do not disable it.

Comment: I agree with your recommendation but it doesn't 'remove all security properties'. It removes the authentication property: but that alone is enough to make the connection insecure, even though it still has the privacy and integrity properties.

Comment: Not it doesn't. Since you don't know **who** you're communicating with, the privacy and integrity properties are lost too. You might be talking to an impostor.

Comment: Of course you are, but your conversation with that imposter is still private and still has integrity, i.e. it is not subject to eavesdropping, injection, or truncation attacks by third parties.

Comment: Yes, but "privacy" and "integrity" usually mean that you protect those two properties **against** adversaries. When you drop authentication checks, you might feed your privacy and integrity straight to the adversaries. And you won't know. Thus, you're not protected.

Comment: "your conversation with that imposter is still private and still has integrity" No : you don't know what your imposter is doing, if it's an insecure MitM, your communications with that imposter is neither private nor has integrity!

Comment: but what if one is certain that it is *not* an impostor? e.g. use only the IP or the domain name is resolved in the `hosts` file, thus guaranteeing that the connection is with the intended party

Comment: @kevinnls: verifying the certificate is the only way you can be really sure that nobody has hijacked the IP or spoofed the name or whatever.

Comment: @DanielStenberg that is of course under the expectation that the certificate has not been compromised